# check in_array for nested array

Tags: php

I have an array in this format, and I want to check if a var is in the array from any of the keys `link`

```
    $nav = array(
        'Account Settings' => array(
            'icon' => 'fa-cog',
            'Account Settings' => array(
                'link' => '/voip/settings?seq='.$seq,
                'icon' => 'fa-cog',
            ),
            'Provisioning' => array(
                'link' => '/voip/provisioning?seq='.$seq,
                'icon' => 'fa-wrench',
            ),
            'E999 Data' => array(
                'link' => '/voip/e999?seq='.$seq,
                'icon' => 'fa-life-ring',
            ),
            'Delete Account' => array(
                'link' => '/voip/delete?seq='.$seq,
                'icon' => 'fa-trash',
            ),
        ),
        'Mailboxes' => array(
            'link' => '/voip/mailboxes?seq='.$seq,
            'icon' => 'fa-envelope',
        ),
        'Telephone Numbers' => array(
            'link' => '/voip/numbers?seq='.$seq,
            'icon' => 'fa-hashtag',
        ),
    );
```

I tried `if(in_array($_GET["nav"], $nav)` but it doesn't pick up the nested values

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, write your own function.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this because you have nested arrays and link can be on different levels. You need to write your own function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the value is in `link` key then you can use array_column to isolate the `link` items.

```
if(in_array($_GET["nav"], array_column($nav['Account Settings'], "link")) || in_array($_GET["nav"], array_column(array_slice($nav, 1), "link"))){
```

This will first look at all link items in account settings, then slice out account settings and look at the other two subarrays for link items.

Test it here:
https://3v4l.org/pP2Nk

Answer (score 0):

There's no readymade function to do that. Let's say you have:

```
$key = 'link';
$value = '/voip/e999?seq=' . $seq;
// and $nav your multidimensionnal array
```

You can write your own recursive function:

```
function contains_key_value_multi($arr, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ( is_array($v) && contains_key_value_multi($v, $key, $value) ||
             $k === $key && $v === $value )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(contains_key_value_multi($nav, $key, $value));
```

---

You can use the [spl classes](https://www.php.net/spl) to be able to loop over leafs of your multidimensionnal array. This time you don't need a recursive function:

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($nav));

function contains_key_value($arr, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ( $k === $key && $v === $value ) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(contains_key_value($ri, $key, $value));
```

---